# How do I block direct access to a URL when not referred by a button click?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this local site where the second page has to only be accessible through a specific button, and not by direct access by writing the URL.

I have this simple example:

Page 1:

```
<html>
<head><title>page 1</title></head>
<body>
<button type="button"><a href="page2.html">to page 2</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<head><title>page 2</title></head>
<body>
<h1>PAGE 2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to rely on the HTTP Referer header to do this since it's **easy to fake**. The client can simply send the refer header along with the request even though they never loaded the first page.

To accomplish this you will need to generate a unique token (*known only to your server and the client*) and require that the second page receive this token in order to load the page.

For example:

```
<?php
function generateToken() {
    return base64_encode(random_bytes(64));
}

session_start(); // start a session to store this token
$_SESSION['token'] = generateToken(); // store the token temporarily in the session
// you can also store it in your database or in memcached if you prefer
?>
<html>
    <head><title>page 1</title></head>
    <body>
        <button type="button">
            <a href="page2.php?token=<?=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['token'])?>">
            to page 2
            </a>
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the second page will need to verify that this token is correct.

```
<?php
session_start(); // load the session data
if (empty($_SESSION['token']) ||
    empty($_GET['token']) ||
    $_GET['token'] !== $_SESSION['token'])
{
    echo "You did not reach this page by the link from page1!";
    exit; // stop the page from loading
}
?>
<html>
    <head><title>page 2</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>PAGE 2</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the button to input and give it a name.

```
<html>
<head><title>page 1</title></head>
<body>
<button type="button"><a href="page2.html">to page 2</a></button>
   <form url="page2.php">
       <input type="button" value="1" name="btn" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
if (isset($_POST['btn']) && $_POST['btn'] == 1) {
// show page 2

} else {

// show error page

}
```